# Nagios 3 how to install RabbitMQ plugin Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, rabbitmq, centreon

I am trying to incorporate a RabbitMQ Server into our Nagios Core 3 running on Ubuntu 12.04.

My searching led me to http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/12/nagios-plugins-rabbitmq/ which seemed quite informative.

When I run the `./check_rabbitmq_server` I encounter an error message `Can't locate Monitoring/Plugin.pm in @INC ...` which led me to the discussion at https://github.com/monitoring-plugins/monitoring-plugin-perl/issues/6

Where can I find the package `libmonitoring-plugin-perl` for Ubuntu 12.04?

Edit: When attempting to run `apt-get install libmonitoring-plugin-perl` the package is not found in Ubuntu 12.04. Only libmonitoring-availability-perl and libmonitoring-livestatus-perl are found in the repository.

Edit #2

I have attempted to install the perl plugin. The command and result are here:

```
cpan[2]> install libmonitoring-plugin-perl
Warning: Cannot install libmonitoring-plugin-perl, don't know what it is.
Try the command

i /libmonitoring-plugin-perl/

to find objects with matching identifiers.

cpan[3]> i /libmonitoring-plugin-perl/
No objects found of any type for argument /libmonitoring-plugin-perl/
```

Thank you.

Steven

Comment: Have you think to install this module via CPAM?

Comment: This may be trivial but the package does exist in Ubuntu's repositories. See http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libmonitoring-plugin-perl -- have you considered using apt-get instead of wget to download/install the package?

Comment: when attempting to run apt-get install libmonitoring-plugin-perl the package is not found in Ubuntu 12.04. Only libmonitoring-availability-perl and libmonitoring-livestatus-perl are found in the repository.

Comment: @RomeoNinov please see my edit #2 above

Comment: @Steven, try to search for libmonitoring or just monitoring and select appropriate

Answer (score 1):

After careful review of the results from the `make test` and additional Google'ing around I found via CPAN console adding numerous Perl libraries resolved the issue. Sorry, I do not recall the 3 or 4 Libraries I had to add. Please refer to the error messages when you run your make test command.